# how to use python request auth and get the cookies at the same time

Tags: python, cookies, request

I am trying to login a web, at first i tried the requests.session:

```
import requests
session=requests.Session()
params={"username":"woniu","password":"password"}
s=session.post(url,params)  
print(s.cookies.get_dict())
```

but login in failed, and there are no cookies return.(I thought maybe this web is a HTTP basic aceess authentication, i can only use auth)

then I tried to use auth of requests

```
from requests.auth import AuthBase
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
auth=HTTPBasicAuth('woniu','password')
r=requests.post(url",auth=auth)
```

this time login in succeed, but still no cookies return.

the problems is: even i login in succeed, when i try to post something, i found myself return to the login page.
is this because i did not handle the cookies? how can i login in successfully and get the cookies at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know for sure that the page:
1. Is HTTPAuth protected
2. Expects a POST request

Then this should work (tested):

```
>>> import requests
>>> url = 'http://.../auth'
>>> r = requests.post(url, data={'post_data': '987654321'},
...                   auth=('user123', 'pass456'))
>>> r
<Response [200]>
>>> r.cookies.items()
[('secret_cookie', '987654321')]
```

Note that POST data is provided with `data` argument, and `HTTP Auth` credentials are provided simply as a tuple `auth`.

Comment: thanks for your help!                                                                                      I am not 100% sure that the page is HTTPAuth protected(does that matter, or how to make sure). do you suggest when i post data, i do the auth at the same time? i tried but seems not work. why the post_data is in the cookies item?

Comment: The server sets the cookie to whatever was POSTed. It's for demonstration purposes, that both POST and Auth work at the same time.

Comment: How do you not know what the page expects you to send? :(

Comment: I use the Fiddler(which is a exe file)， it's a free web debugging tool. i just started using it，still not know for sure。

Comment: in my problem，there are many data need to send，i only choose some of them， maybe need to post all the data that Fiddler shows。

Comment: Fiddler shows you all requests, right? Then just send everything with your browser and look at how data is beint sent, how auth is done, etc.

Comment: I try to post more data as the Fiddler showed， and do the auth in the same time . it worked, thanks!